# How to filter SQL query by using SSRS Yes or No Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How to pass Yes or No parameter to SQL Query in SSRS.
I have set @MyParam Values to 1 and 0. 
If parameter  "Yes" should include the result with types "Direct" with others.
If "No" Then result should be without "Direct" with others.

Help would be immensely appreciated as usual! :)

My Query:

```
SELECT EQ_WO_ID, EQ_WO_ID, job_type FROM EQ
WHERE ((@MyParam = 1 and job_type='Direct') or (@MyParam = 0 and job_type not null))
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic you describe is:

```
WHERE ((@MyParam = 1) or
       (@MyParam = 0 and job_type <> 'Direct')
      )
```

If `job_type` can be `NULL`, you need to take that into account for the `0` condition.

Comment: If @MyParam = 1 result should be all job_types including 'Direct'

Answer (score 2):

Just another option.  (my read is contains DIRECT or not).

MyParam can be a BIT or INT

```
 ....   
 Where sign(patindex('%Direct%',job_type))=@MyParam
```

Comment: If @MyParam = 1 then, result should be all job_types including 'Direct'  , If '0' then all job_types  except 'Direct'